# gcp service account with role owner doesn't give permission to all resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Gcp service account with role owner doesn't give permission to all resources. I created a ticket on googles issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78143615

Note: In the ticket there are screen shots and a link to my github repo (very small amount of terraform code)

Comment: I see that you are already getting support from Google Cloud. Maybe it would be a good idea to answer this question yourself when they found the issue.